# error in resource_stream() in Python

Tags: python

I have the following Python file structure:

```
package1
    +-- config.cfg
    +-- system.py
```

Then, system.py accesses config.cfg using

```
with pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'config.cfg') as fp:
     ...
```

This code runs fine in my PyCharm IDE but when I bundle the codes into an egg and then run "Python egg_file", I get the following error:

IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'package1/config.cfg'

I tried to fix this error for several errors but no luck...:(